# Upload multiple files to an Amazon S3 bucket using Sails.js?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, sails.js

I want to upload multiple files to an Amazon S3 bucket using Sails.js. I'm able to upload a single file to Amazon S3, but I'm not able to upload multiple files with getting the error: `max buffer error`.

Comment: what package are you using for uploading files?

Comment: here i am using ,aws-sdk and  skipper-s3 module for uploading s3, for one file working fine

Comment: use multer for uploading multiple files using multipart upload